# How to add items from listbox to listview?

Tags: c#, listview, listbox

My code i called up during runtime  and the following data are displayed in the listbox. 
How can i add the name and the number separately from the listbox in the listview columns ?
The result in the ListBox should look as shown below:

```
        foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            string drop = item.ToString();
            ListViewItem itemToAdd = new ListViewItem(drop);
            listView1.Items.Add(itemToAdd);             
        }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: have you created the columns in the designer for the listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By splitting each line of the `ListBox` on the comma, you can add each element of the split array (`drop`) into a `ListViewItem` and add that to your `ListView`.

Note that the first 2 lines are not needed if you have already added the columns to the listview via the designer.

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Subject");
listView1.Columns.Add("Grade");
listView1.View = View.Details;

foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
{
    var drop = item.Split(',');
    ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem();
    li.Text = drop[0].Trim();
    li.SubItems.Add(drop[1].Trim());
    listView1.Items.Add(li);
}
```